# How can I get the VS Code syntax highlighting to look like Stack Overflow's?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

[random screenshot of a Stackoverflow code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjAbj.jpg)
see

I have issues with coding in day light. Specially the color. I feel lost in dark theme, doesn't matter how beautiful or intriguing it is. Tried lots and lots of day theme including VS Code default. Could be hundred plus theme I have tried. Most probably, I'm color blind. Didn't test though. Anyway, nowhere I feel comfortable except the code snippet of Stack Overflow (Not funny, it's true). We all know how it looks like.

How can I get the VS Code syntax highlighting to look like Stack Overflow's?

Comment: you can change all syntax highlight colors in your settings.json

Answer (score 2):

From searching "`@category:"themes" "stack overflow"`" in the extension search bar (which searches the VS Code marketplace), at the time of this writing, there is only the following <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with these extensions)</sub></sup>:

- [`xynny.stack-overflow`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xynny.stack-overflow) which has no readme and no repository link, which just gives me sketchy vibes and I'm not downloading this onto my machine.
- [`richellyItalo.stack-manibu-overflow`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richellyItalo.stack-manibu-overflow), which is only Light Mode (and I'm not sure about how good the theme is in general (I think I recall comments on problems with it)), but it is [MIT licensed](https://github.com/richellyitalo/vscode-theme-stack-manibu-overflow/blob/master/LICENSE), so if you want, you can fork and modify it to Dark Mode following the terms of the license. If you do create and publish a theme based on it, please also comment here with a link to it so I can update this answer.

You can also build it yourself. See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme.

Stack Exchange's syntax highlighting functionality is built using highlight.js. For more info on Stack Exchange's syntax highlighting features, see [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/997587) on meta.stackexchange.com.

If you open up your browser's developer tools in a Stack Exchange site, you can find the CSS variables that are defined. For example at the time of this writing, the following are defined for Dark Mode on Stack Overflow:

```css
--highlight-bg: hsl(0,2%,11%);
--highlight-color: var(--black);
--highlight-comment: hsl(0,0%,60%);
--highlight-punctuation: hsl(0,0%,80%);
--highlight-namespace: hsl(27,85%,61.5%);
--highlight-attribute: hsl(207,41.5%,67%);
--highlight-literal: hsl(27,85%,61.5%);
--highlight-symbol: hsl(306,43%,69%);
--highlight-keyword: hsl(208,41.5%,67%);
--highlight-variable: hsl(65.5,39%,57.5%);
--highlight-addition: var(--green-600);
--highlight-deletion: var(--red-700);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Stack Manibu Overflow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richellyItalo.stack-manibu-overflow&ssr=false#overview)

Exactly the same color schemes.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richellyItalo.stack-manibu-overflow&ssr=false#overview

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find out a Stack Overflow code theme for you, but I found three light themes for you, maybe one serves. Of these ones, I prefer the "Quiet Light for VSC". The themes are:

1 - [Quiet Light for VSC](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecrayon.theme-quietlight-vsc)

[image: Quiet Light theme]

2 - [Iceberg for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cocopon.iceberg-theme)

[image: Iceberg theme]

3 - [vue-color](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=staychan.vue-color)

[image: Vue Color theme]

But if no one of these serves for you, maybe you have to change the color of your theme manually to put it how you want.